# C++: Is there a way to pass system arguments/files directly at compilation with g++

Tags: c++, bash, g++

I have a C++ program which uses sys.argv for loop counters and an input file to initialize std::vector's. Can I directly input those at compilation with g++?
I would also be happy with something that uses bash to do this. I am not proficient enough in either C++ or bash to figure this out myself.

Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: Not at compilation time, but you typically use bash input redirection at runtime like so: `my_program < input.txt`

Comment: probably not the solution for your specific problem, but `#include foo` does just that. The include directive is replaced with the contents of the file `foo`

Comment: If I had a file like: "x y vx vy\n" N times. Could I convert this with #include to a couple of std::vector's in the C++ file?

Answer (score 1):

C++ is compiled before it is executed. That means that the compiler won't have a list of arguments to give to the program.

Consider the scenario where you build the C++ program on one computer but then distribute the C++ program to another computer. The second computer doesn't have, or need, a compiler. How do you get your program arguments then? Consider this example in Python:

```py
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
  print(arg)
```

In [C++20](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YYo1TE), that might be:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <cstdlib> // EXIT_SUCCESS

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you know the program arguments for the second computer when you compiled it into the first computer then you can provide it as a static variable. Consider these examples:

```py
my_args = ["hello", "world!"]
for arg in my_args:
  print(arg)
```

In [C++20](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4qe755), that might be:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <cstdlib> // EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <vector> // std::vector

std::vector<const char *> my_args{"hello", "world!"};
int main(int, char **) {
    for (const char * arg : my_args) {
        std::cout << arg << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```